# Gallery layout_height set to wrap_content in ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-gallery, layoutparams

I have ListView with My Custom Adapter. The problem is, that gallery view is very hight, althought there is wrap_content in layout_height. How I can fix it?

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context ctx;
LayoutInflater lInflater;
Integer[] objects;

ListViewAdapter(Context context, Integer[] images) {
    ctx = context;
    objects = images;
    lInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return objects.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return objects[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (position==1){
        View galleryView =lInflater.inflate(R.layout.galerry_view,parent,false);
        final Gallery gallery = (Gallery) galleryView.findViewById(R.id.gallery1);
        gallery.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(ctx));
        return galleryView;
    }
    ImageView view=new ImageView(ctx);
    view.setImageResource(objects[position]);
    return view;
}
}
```

As you can see it inflates gallery when position==1. 
 There is galerry xml layout and gallery adapter:

```
<Gallery   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/gallery1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Gallery adapter "ImageAdapter":

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private int mGalleryItemBackground;
private Context mContext;
private final Integer[] mImage = {R.drawable.tmp_poster1, R.drawable.tmp_poster2};

public ImageAdapter(Context ctx){
    mContext=ctx;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mImage.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mImage[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return  mImage[position];
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ImageView view = new ImageView(mContext);
    view.setImageResource(mImage[position]);
    view.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
    view.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);

    return view;
}
}
```

[screenshot:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iB4Yv.jpg)

Comment: you are not really supposed to put scrollables in a scrollable.

Comment: @njzkl2 Yes, maybe galerry in scrollview, but not scrollView in ScrollView. And I want understand what is the problem in this example to anderstand android better.

Comment: the galleryview is greedy because it does not know how much space it will need.

Comment: But I'm return galleryView after setting galerryAdapter, and gallery adapter know How many space it need, doesn't it?